# Loop for generating html inputs to processingjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, processing

I am trying to use html input fields to control a sketch. Now I want to make a loop to generate more then one input.

```js
var uivars = {
 tA: "40",  // set initial values
 tB: "10",
};
```

Then I refer to those variables in the sketch:

```html
<script type="application/processing" data-processing-target="pjs">
void draw() {
background(255);
var a = uivars.tA;
var b = uivars.tB;
line(0,b,a,b);
}
</script>
```

Then I get the values from the input fields and update the uivar variable in the beginning:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#word_textboxA").keyup(function () {                 // whenever text is entered into input box...
  uivars.tA = $(this).val();                          // update word variable,
  });
 $("#word_textboxB").keyup(function () {                 // whenever text is entered into input box...
  uivars.tB = $(this).val();
  });
 $("#word_textboxA").val(uivars.tA);                // initialize input textbox contents.
 $("#word_textboxB").val(uivars.tB);                // initialize input textbox contents.
});
</script>
```

And the inputs:

```html
<div id="PVarray">
 <input type="text" id="word_textboxA"/><br/>
 <input type="text" id="word_textboxB"/>
<div/>
```

I am building a sketch using processing js and will have over 40 inputs. So I am looking for a way to make a loop for these steps.

No I've managed to generate a number of input fields putting this somewhere:

```html
<!-- <script>
window.onload = initAll;
function initAll(){
 for(var i = 0; i<=1; i++)
 {
  var c=document.getElementById('PVarray');
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type','text');
  input.setAttribute('size','1');
  
  input.setAttribute('id','num'+(i+1));
  input.setAttribute('value', 'id' );
  //Adds first input to container
  c.appendChild(input);
  input = '';
 }
 document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = uivars.tA;
}
</script> -->
```

But I just cannot find a way to refer in the jquery part to the changing id's of the html inputs.
I am not a experienced programmer. I looked around to find the answer but this is just a difficult one for me. My sketch will need over 40 inputs. the loop should just generate the html inputs, set the initial variables, update the variables on inputchange and give the values to the sketch. The names of the inputs and initial values can be put in a array.

Comment: Do `uivars` properties need to be `.tA`, `.tB`, `.tC` etc? It would be much simpler if they were `.t0`, `.t1`, `.t2` etc.

Comment: It doens't matter to me what the names in the in between steps are. So yes i think that not a problem.

Comment: OK, ignore that. I've just realised - it's not important. Solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the solution is quite simple.

You tagged the question with "jQuery", so here is a jQuery solution.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //This is the keyup event handler, attached below to all <input> elements
    function updateUivars() {
        uivars[this.id] = this.value;
    }

    //a jQuery-wrapped reference to the PVarray container
    var $c = $('#PVarray');

    //Loop through uivars properties to create <input> elements with :
    // - id equal to the property (the key)
    // - an initial value equal to uivars[key]
    $.each(uivars, function(key, value) {
        $('<input type="text" size="1" />').attr('id', key).val(value).appendTo($c).on('keyup', updateUivars);
    });
});
```

### EDIT

So now, for each univars property, there is one value and two pieces of associated text.

```
var uivars = {
    Ins: [30, "Insulation", "kWh/m2/day"],
    D:   [40, "Deterioration", "%"], 
    AO:  [10, "Azimuth Offset", "%"],
    SD:  [20, "Surface Deposits", "%"],
    TC:  [30, "Temperature", "DegC"]
};
```

The loop that creates the input elements clearly needs to be amended to cause the associated text to be displayed.

Maybe it is less clear that the keyup event handler also needs to be modified to store values back in element [0] of the appropriate array.

Something like this should do it :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //This is the keyup event handler, attached below to all <input> elements
    function updateUivars() {
        uivars[this.id][0] = this.value;
    }

    //a jQuery-wrapped reference to the PVarray container
    var $c = $('#PVarray');

    //Loop through uivars properties to create an inner div containing:
    // - a label for the property's name
    // - an <input> elements with :
    //   * id equal to the property (the key)
    //   * an initial value equal to uivars[key][0]
    // - a label for the property's units
    $.each(uivars, function(key, arr) {
        var $div = $('<div class="property"/>').appendTo($c);//inner block element
        $('<label/>').text(arr[1]).appendTo($div);
        $('<input type="text" size="3" />').attr('id', key).val(arr[0]).appendTo($div).on('keyup', updateUivars);
        $('<label/>').text(arr[2]).appendTo($div);
    });
});
```

If desired, the inner divs can be styled in CSS with a `.property {...}` directive.

Comment: No worries. I hope the comments provide adequate explanation.

Comment: Hi, Another question, what could  use in stead of the uivars object if I want to have more "values"? for example for each entry Key,value1,value2,value3. ?

Comment: @GeertvanWees, in that case, you could still use the `uivars` object but each of its properties would need to be an object or array containing the values. The javascript would need to be adapted accordingly.

Comment: yes, i think i did so in the code below, hower the processingjs does not work right anymore. its does't find the right value in the array after change i think..

Comment: Ah, thanks again. this worked. So the introduction of the variable is just to be able to change the elements' style with css? So that all elements will be styled the same way? Or does it also have to do with updating the uivars correctly?

Comment: Styling is a separate issue. I only mentioned it to make you aware of the possibility of styling the generated content. If `class="property"` is left out and/or there is no CSS directive, then the javascript will still work.